# How to get static type checking and auto-complete for the parse method?

Tags: typescript, zod

Let's say I have the code:

```js
import { z } from "zod"
export const Book = z.object({
  type: z.literal("book"),
  title: z.string(),
  published: z.number().int().min(1900)
});

const result = Book.parse({
    type: "book",
    title: hopefullyString,
    published: possiblyNumber
    // ...
})
```

The `Book.parse` method takes an `unknown`, so I don't have type checking or auto-complete for the parameter. Is there an alternative method that takes a `z.infer<typeof Book>` or something similar?

How should I statically type check the input?

*Tried to make the code clearer*

Comment: Why would you want to validate something at runtime if you statically can validate it when transpiling? Seems very pointless.

Comment: @super You mean, what's the point of zod? Also, ideally you want both.

Comment: No. I use zod myself, it's a very good lib IMO. What I mean is that `const book: Book = { ... }` makes sense. What you are doing does not. The whole point of validation is to take some unknown input and validate it. Taking something that is known and already checked and then again validate it is pointless.

Comment: Oh. I see what you mean. The data is just full of anyes and type asserted values at a deeper level. It's very much not known but rather "optimistically assumed". I want to validate the deeper layer but I also want to have auto-completion for the parts that I'm writing.

Comment: Statically checked input can let you avoid runtime bugs that could have been caught during development. E.g. if you update the zod schema of a type but forget to update the place where the object gets created, you wouldn't know about the error until your application reaches that line of code.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I checked the documentation and there isn't anything. Anyway, I ended up defining:

```js
export type Book = z.infer<typeof Book>;
```

And whenever I want auto-complete in the parse method, I do this:

```js
Book.parse({
    type: "book",
    published: thing,
    title: otherThing
} satisfies Book)
```

Using the new [satisfies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html) operator. Not exactly the intended use, but it works for me. `as` would be too assertive.